# Why does .clone() duplicate elements multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of divs that contain ULs. In each UL, I need to change the text of a specific LI and clone content from another element.

So far I've been able to do this. However, I can't figure out why the cloned element (.calDesc span) is being duplicated. Any thoughts on why this is occurring? And is there a workaround?

```
<!-- LINE ITEM -->
<div class="rateTypeLineItems">
    <!-- Non-Best Flex Rate -->
    <div class="regularRates roomsView"> <span>Advance Saver Rate & Deals</span>

    </div>
    <!-- Best Flexible Rate -->
    <div class="regularRates roomsView">
        <input name="upsellParentRateCode" type="hidden" value="IGCOR">
        <div class="upsellHeader"> <span class="groupHeader">Best Flexible Rate &amp; Deals</span>

        </div>
        <div class="defaultRateInfo">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(240, 118, 5);">Free Cancellation From <span>May-29-2014 to May-30-2014</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>No deposit required</li>
                    <li>Breakfast included</li>
                    <li>Most popular rate</li>
                    <li>View Rate Details</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="regularRates roomsView"> <span> There is no rate for this room</span>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- CONTENT THAT IS BEING CLONED -->
<p class="calDesc" style="margin:40px 0; background:red; color:white;"><span>May-29-2014 &nbsp;to&nbsp; May-30-2014
  &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> &nbsp; • &nbsp; 1&nbsp;Adult, 1&nbsp;Room &nbsp; • &nbsp; <a class="selectDatesControl" href="#selectDatesForm" id="editDate" name="editDate" title="Select to change your search">Change Search</a></p>
```

---

```
//move each Best Flex div above all siblings
$('.rateTypeLineItems').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.regularRates.roomsView').has(':input[value="IGCOR"]').prependTo(this);
});

//find and change date information
$('.rateTypeLineItems').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.upSellContainer .defaultRateInfo div ul li:contains("Refund")').text('Free Cancellation From ').css({
        'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': '#F07605'
    });

});

//find each parent, clone date range and insert after .defaultRateInfo
$('.defaultRateInfo li:contains("Free Cancellation From ")').each(function () {
    $('.calDesc span').clone().appendTo('.defaultRateInfo li:contains("Free Cancellation From ")');
});
```

Here's a link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/7e45N/7/).

Comment: your fiddle has the span inside of the li's already, why are you appending a second one to each? copy paste error?

Comment: You misinterpreted the results (as did i initially). It isn't duplicating the span at all, it's just that the original code already has the span there! however, if you did have two li's that matched, the result would be 3 each instead of two. my answer solves that second issue which is not presented in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes, my fingers aren't working as they should today. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are re-selecting the li's on each iteration.

```
.appendTo('.defaultRateInfo li:contains("Free Cancellation From ")')
```

you should instead target the current li.

```
.appendTo(this)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7e45N/8/ (i removed the extra span that was already in the li, not sure why it was there to begin with)

Comment: Yeah, I inadvertently copy/pasted that.

Looks like your suggestion did the trick!!

Thanks!